# Import Product Data w/ CSV from command line (not dataflow)

Tags: magento-1.9, import, importexport, dataflow

I've updated a development version of my store to `1.9.2.4` from `1.7.0.2`. I noticed that a [plugin](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/amartinez-customimportexport.html) I used to handle inventory updates from the command line no longer works. I have over 15K products and the old admin importer used to stall while processing (hence the reason for using the plugin). However, the `1.9.2.4` version works great.

Is there a way to import and update products using a csv file from the command line and have it process it the same way as logging into the admin and going to "System > Import/Export > Import" by creating a script and setting up a cron job? I would use the [dataflow process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856841/magento-possible-to-run-export-profile-from-shell-ssh), but it takes several minutes to process and we are trying to keep the inventory updated every 15 minutes. The dataflow process can take longer than that depending on the amount of products that need to be updated, but the regular import only take a few seconds.

Answer (score -1):

I arrived here searching for a way to do the same for magento 2. For magento 1.9, I used and am still using [magmi](http://magmi.org/) with a variety of input sources. Very easy to use via a `cron` job, and good management of configurable products.